# Passing a russian rss feed in ios

Tags: ios, encoding

i am parsing a russian RSS using NSURLCOnnection. the issue that i am facing is when i parsed

I get russian string now i am trying to convert it into dictionary but not able to convert as it is always returning nil.

here is my code

```
NSString*     responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData        encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
NSError*      error;
NSDictionary* dicfromStr  = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:responseStr error:&error];
```

Here is sample xml that i am getting

```
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>TEST DATA</title>
    <language>ru</language>
    <description>TEST DATA</description>
    <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/rss/</link>
    <pubDate>Wed, 12 Dec 2012 10:44:06 +0600</pubDate>
    <generator>KohanaPHP</generator>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/187</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/187</guid>
      <description>TEST DATA</description>
      <pubDate>Tue, 11 Dec 2012 18:45:13 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/186</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/186</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Tue, 11 Dec 2012 17:44:10 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/185</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/185</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Tue, 11 Dec 2012 15:39:22 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/184</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/184</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Mon, 10 Dec 2012 19:36:05 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/183</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/183</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Mon, 10 Dec 2012 19:26:48 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/182</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/182</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Mon, 10 Dec 2012 16:00:43 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/181</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/181</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 07 Dec 2012 20:00:01 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/180</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/180</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 07 Dec 2012 19:54:40 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/179</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/179</guid>
      <description>manish jain</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/178</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/178</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 06 Dec 2012 21:20:57 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/177</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/177</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 06 Dec 2012 21:16:06 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/176</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/176</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 06 Dec 2012 15:43:40 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/175</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/175</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 05 Dec 2012 19:30:46 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/174</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/174</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 05 Dec 2012 19:26:38 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/173</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/173</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 05 Dec 2012 15:41:08 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/171</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/171</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Tue, 04 Dec 2012 19:11:41 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/170</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/170</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Tue, 04 Dec 2012 19:05:07 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/169</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/169</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Tue, 04 Dec 2012 18:53:50 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/168</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/168</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Tue, 04 Dec 2012 18:49:23 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/167</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/167</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Mon, 03 Dec 2012 20:19:42 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/166</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/166</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Mon, 03 Dec 2012 18:56:53 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/164</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/164</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Mon, 03 Dec 2012 17:03:21 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/162</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/162</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 30 Nov 2012 16:28:05 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/161</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/161</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Fri, 30 Nov 2012 16:21:56 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/159</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/159</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 29 Nov 2012 19:11:38 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/158</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/158</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 29 Nov 2012 19:06:06 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/157</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/157</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 29 Nov 2012 18:27:57 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/155</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/155</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 28 Nov 2012 19:27:58 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/154</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/154</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 28 Nov 2012 19:24:02 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/152</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/152</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Tue, 27 Nov 2012 19:02:32 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/151</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/151</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Tue, 27 Nov 2012 18:53:11 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/150</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/150</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Tue, 27 Nov 2012 18:41:16 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/149</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/149</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Tue, 27 Nov 2012 18:26:07 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/147</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/147</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Mon, 26 Nov 2012 21:21:23 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/141</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/141</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 22 Nov 2012 20:34:33 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/140</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/140</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 22 Nov 2012 20:19:16 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Michael Jackson. The legend continues.</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/136</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/136</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 22 Nov 2012 15:33:42 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/134</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/134</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 21 Nov 2012 20:34:39 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>The Cyprus investors show 2013</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/133</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/133</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 21 Nov 2012 20:31:56 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/132</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/132</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 21 Nov 2012 20:25:09 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/128</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/128</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Tue, 20 Nov 2012 19:22:08 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>TEST DATA</title>
      <link>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/100</link>
      <guid>http://russianwave.com.cy/news/show/100</guid>
      <description>manish jain</description>
      <pubDate>Thu, 08 Nov 2012 20:35:04 +0600</pubDate>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: yes it is valid xml just in russian

Comment: I've tested `XMLReader` class with the russian values and it worked just fine. Can you provide a sample XML ?

Comment: @A-Live i have added xml in my question.please have a look

Comment: It doesn't have the closing tags for 'channel' and 'rss' elements, was it truncated ?

Comment: actually i just copied half to give you an idea. this xm i am getting using this line of code     NSString* newStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]; but not able to create dictionary.so hard to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the XML is well-formated (which we can't know until you show the full document), the part you've shown is still a part of an invalid XML. You can't use `&nbsp` entities at XML document until you explicitly declare it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml:spaces [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ]>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>\u041d\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0438</title>
        <language>ru</language> .....
```

Please check the [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd.asp) for details.

Comment: HI A-Live i appreciate for your answer i have updated complete xml that i am getting but still i am unable to convert it in dictionary using xmlreader

Comment: @user1894320 Could you try it after fixing the format issue at `<description>manish jain</pubDate>` ?

Comment: description tag i am getting this <description>
 &nbsp;

 \u0411\u0440\u0438\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0446\u044b \u043d\u0430\u0447\u0430\u043b\u0438 \u0434\u0435\u043b\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043a\u0438 \u043d\u0430 \u0442\u043e\u0442\u0430\u043b\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0435, \u043f\u044b\u0442\u0430\u044f\u0441\u044c \u0443\u0433\u0430\u0434\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0438\u043c\u044f, \u043a\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043d\u0446 \u0423\u0438\u043b\u044c\u044f\u043c \u0438 \u0435\u0433\u043e \u0436\u0435\u043d\u0430 ...</description>

Comment: @user1894320 You either replace all `&nbsp;` with `&#160;` (or space) manually or simply add `<!DOCTYPE xml:spaces [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ]>` at the top of the document to let the parser know how how to handle it, see the snippet at answer.